# Recursive Pascal's triangle (Combination func) Assembly

Tags: assembly, recursion, x86-64, pascals-triangle, yasm

I am trying to write a **recursive combination function** in assembly (**Yasm** (similar to nsam)). 
I cannot use loops, multiplication or division.

I certain I am on the right track but am having issues once I hit the second inner function call. Can anyone help me and tell me where I am going wrong?

**Edit:** This is my updated code which returns a result but is not always correct. I think I must have a small bit of logic incorrect.

```
    mov     rax, [n]
    push    rax
    mov     rax, [k]
    push    rax
    call    func    
    ...     ...     program continues from here

 func:                      
    push    rbp 
    mov     rbp, rsp

    push    rdi
    push    rsi

    cmp     rsi, 0
    je      stopcond
    cmp     rdi, rsi
    jne     contin

stopcond:
    mov     rax, 1
    jmp     endfunc
contin:
    ;C(n-1,k-1)
    mov     rax, [rsp]  ; This is k
    dec     rax
    mov     rdx, rax
    mov     rax, [rsp+8]  ; This is n
    dec     rax
    mov     rsi, rdx
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    func

    mov     rbx, rax
    mov     rax, [rsp+8]  ; This is n
    dec     rax
    mov     rdx, rax
    mov     rax, [rsp]  ; This is k
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     rdi, rdx
    call    func

    add     rax, rbx

endfunc:
    add     rsp, 16
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

This is a javascript implementation I have been using as a reference

```
function(n,k) {
    if ( k==0 || k==n ) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return C(n-1,k-1) + C(n-1,k)
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's all of your code you're going to have issues when `func` eventually returns, since `func:` directly follows `call func`.

Comment: That's what I thought but when I look at c->assembly conversion of this `int func(int n,int k){if(k==0||k==n){return 1;}else{return func(n-1,k-1)+func(n-1,k);}}` here http://assembly.ynh.io/ they do a very similar thing @Michael

Comment: That C code does not include the initial call to `func`.

Comment: This is it here, the only interesting thing is it puts `n` & `k` into `edi` & `esi` respectively

`int func(int n,int k){if(k==0||k==n){return 1;}else{return func(n-1,k-1)+func(n-1,k);}}int main(){int a=func(3,2);return 0;}`

Comment: Some important things to note if you're looking at the assembly output at that website is that A) the call from `main` to `func` is located _after_ the body of `func`, not before it like in your code, and that B) after `func` returns to `main` there's a `ret` to return back to the C runtime that call the `main` function.

Comment: @Michael, sorry I misread your first question. No this is no all the code, just the bare essentials to show the function call.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `C(n-1,k)` invocation is incorrect, because both `rax` and `rbx` have already been decremented and the recursive invocation destroys their value anyway. The simple fix is to reload the arguments from the stack.
2. Similarly, the recursive invocation will use `rdx` for its own temporary, thereby overwriting the caller's copy. Solution: you should allocate a local variable on the stack, and use that as temporary storage.
3. You are not restoring the stack pointer. At `endfunc` you should insert a `mov esp, ebp`.
4. You are not following the usual calling convention. This is not a problem if you agree with the caller, but might still be a good idea to do so. You can get a quick overview at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI).

PS: The usual advice applies: learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes.

Comment: Brilliant. I am looking at the assembly output for a C equivalent program and can see certain conventions being used.